# Group by query returning only latest result - Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, date, group-by

I have the following query, where I want to retrieve the earliest/latest date for each group.

Each group can have many members who are travelling at different dates, so I want to know what is the earliest date within that group between those members. Similarly this is done with all existing groups and then displayed in the chosen order.

This is the query I'm using:

```
public function sortByDate($order, $year)
    {
        $this->db->select('groups.*, general_info.proposed_date_of_arrival');
        $this->db->from('groups');
        $this->db->join('general_info', 'general_info.group_id = groups.group_id');
        $this->db->where('YEAR(groups.group_year)', $year);
        $this->db->group_by('groups.group_id');
        $this->db->order_by("general_info.proposed_date_of_arrival", $order);
        $val = $this->db->get();
    }
```

But the above only returns and compares the latest/most recent entries to each group, which isn't the type of query that should be generated.

An output of the results:

```
array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'group_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'group_leader_name' => string 'Bob' (length=7)
          'group_year' => string '2013-11-01' (length=10)
          'year' => string '2013' (length=4)
          'proposed_date_of_arrival' => string '2014-02-22' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array (size=5)
          'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'group_leader_name' => string 'John' (length=7)
          'group_year' => string '2013-11-12' (length=10)
          'year' => string '2013' (length=4)
          'proposed_date_of_arrival' => string '2014-12-15' (length=10)
```

There are actually two members each in these two test groups, the earliest in group 1 having a proposed date of arrival of 2013-12-31 and the earliest in group 2 being 2014-01-19.

The actual output of ordering in ascending order should be the group with the date of 2013-12-31 being first, and the group with the date of 2014-01-19 being next. However, I get the above array result instead, which is comparing the two most recent members instead of taking into account all the members proposed dates. How can I compare between all the members dates?

Comment: @smcjones Why did you delete your post? I tried out the query with limit but it only returns the first row, i.e. no other groups are returned except the first one. Maybe I'm a bit thick lol. I can maybe try to query the number of groups, and pass that as a variable to the limit parameter?

Comment: @smcjones c'mon dude, iso opinions :)

Comment: I failed to understand what you were looking to retrieve. It was totally off topic. Didn't want to waste your time further. More tired than I realized!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is the solution

```
public function sortByArrivalDateASC($year)
    {
        $this->db->select('groups.*, MIN(date(general_info.proposed_date_of_arrival)) as proposed_date_of_arrival');
        $this->db->from('groups');
        $this->db->join('general_info', 'general_info.group_id = groups.group_id');
        //$this->db->where('YEAR(groups.group_year)', $year);
        $this->db->group_by('group_id');
        $val = $this->db->get();
    }
```

I was missing an aggregate function to *group by*. I figured I don't really need to implement a descending order, since we only want to know the earliest time of departure.

[Thanks to GROUP_BY MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and [this w3schools explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Just if someone could confirm, MIN() is the same as order_by 'ASC' right? I get the same result if I add the order_by clause, but just want to confirm in case there are slight differences

Comment: Dont think that will get the result you want. check this out. Don't know how to convert it but seems to be the answer. http://www.cafewebmaster.com/mysql-order-sort-group

Comment: Thanks I will look into that, I also came across some results which showed "nested" queries but am also struggling to understand how to implement that in active record form (maybe separate the queries into different functions somehow, idk). Thank you btw for coming back and posting that blog, will look into it further.